# Why do I get a 404 for my sitemap index after installing Yoast?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sitemap, google-xml-sitemaps

I just installed [the Yoast plugin](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/) on my Wordpress blog, so that I can automatically create my sitemap xml. However when I visit the page sitemap_index.xml I get a "404 page not found" error. Why isn't my sitemap there?

Answer (score 5):

Go to Admin > Settings > Permalinks and click save without altering anything

"Sometimes resetting the permalink structure will quickly solve a 404 error from a recent change to your installation."

See http://kb.yoast.com/article/77-my-sitemap-index-is-giving-a-404-error-what-should-i-do for further details

Comment: That didn't work for me.

Comment: I used to install AIOSEO, and uninstalled it now. Then go to the native wordpress sitemap "/wp-sitemap.xml" gave me 404. Reset the permalink did solve the 404 error. I don't know where it fix the redirection, but it worked.